# Trouble with KNN on OpenCV, new_samples.type() == CV_32F when training

Tags: numpy, opencv, python-3.7

I am trying to set a simple KNN problem implementation with a three class dataset but whenever I try to execute the train function I keep the said `(-215:Assertion failed) new_samples.type() == CV_32F in function 'cv::ml::Impl::train error.`

I have tried reshaping the responses array into many different things since most of the errors came from that part of the code, that goes from `1 x n` matrix to a single list. I am following this tutorial. I can get it done with two classes by defining my own data just like I do with three classes but I can't manage to train with three classes.

```py
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv 

classA=([(10,1,1),(9,2,2),(11,1,2),(8,3,2),(7,2,3),(8,5,4),(9,3,4),(6,6,5),(8,6,6),(9,7,7)])
classB=([(5,1,20),(5,2,19),(5,1,21),(4,2,18),(4,1,19),(6,3,20),(6,2,19),(4,4,18),(4,5,21),(6,4,19)])
classC=([(5,14,10),(6,13,9),(4,12,11),(6,11,9),(6,7,12),(7,6,13),(7,7,10), (7,8,11),(8,8,12),(7,6,11)])

points = classA + classB + classC
responses = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])

# Using numpy's array?
points_np = np.asarray(points)
responses_np = np.asarray(responses).reshape((30,1))
#print(points_np)
#print(responses_np)

knn = cv.ml.KNearest_create()
knn.train(points_np, cv.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses_np)
```

I know both sample and response data should follow a similar structure so the function can associate each point to a class but I think my issue is on the type of structure I am using for the responses variable. **How should I shape or set the responses variable in order to be readable for the train function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the assertion, the data type for samples must be `CV_32F`, which stands for 32 bit float.

```
points_np = np.asarray(points).astype(np.float32)
responses_np = np.asarray(responses).reshape((30,1)).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I am still learning Python and sometimes I tunnel into many stuff whenever then answer is this "easy".